# Forwarding http GET via php

Tags: php, android, http

My Android app downloads images from my webspace.
I have no ssl.
I don't want the user to see where the images are stored. The folder with images should be secured via .htaccess.
So I thought to send the GET request to a php script and it collects the image and responses it to the android client.

Can someone give me a hint how to do the forwarding?

Comment: HTTPS or not, someone can still figure out where your images are stored.  Besides, what is the point of your PHP script if they can just hit the PHP script to get at the images?

Comment: I thought of retrieving it locally on the Server and serve it via the php script. The http get will Contain an MD5 from Übername Pass and a Nonce. So via pc you cannot Access the php

Comment: @tobias: so instead of people getting the images directly, they'll just tell your script to get the images for them. you cannot make this system "secure".

Comment: PLZ read my comment above. The php Script Checks MD5

Comment: @tobias, `readfile()` is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to do this is to keep the images outside the webroot. This way they can't be accessed by going to a url. In the php you can then do something like:

```
//Check username/whatever

//Decide what file we want
$theFile = getTheFile();

//Display the file
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
readfile('../not/web/accessible/'.$theFile);
die();
```

Answer (score 0):

To download something from somewhere else use [`curl`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php). You really should cache downloaded content on your server. Reconstructing GET request from $_GET and $_SERVER variables should be easy, just follow examples on linked page.

But I think you want to look at "[reverse proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy)". There are existing solution  of enterprise quality for this task.